# Overlay SVG path on top of image with object-fit cover

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive, absolute

I am trying to overlay an SVG path on top of an image: https://gsap-svg-motion-path.webflow.io/

The image should take up full browser height (100vh) and have object-fit cover. I'm having trouble positioning the SVG path and maintaining responsiveness.

FYI I'm building it in Webflow, so the  lives inside another div with class html-embed.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for the response. right now the SVG has viewBox="0 0 325.19 473.83" (rectangular image). I'm having trouble with scaling the SVG at the same rate as the background image which has the object-fit=cover property. Sorry for the lack of details I didn't quite know how to describe other than provide a link to the build.

Comment: Can you give us the basis of your HTML structure. It sounds as though you have a container element around the image (as you want it to be sized with 100vh height but cover - i.e. some of it may be cut off at the sides.)